# Trying to make a Sum of Values in Python has diferent value from excel

Tags: python, sum

I am trying to make a sum of values from database Titanic_train where I Want to sum Ages groupby Survived then when I use `df.groupby('Survived').sum()` the results per Survived has diferent results when I count from Excel file.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_excel('titanic_train.xls')
df.isnull().sum()
df.dropna(axis=0)
df.groupby('Survived').sum()
```

in Python the results is:
Survived 0 2481 and Excel
Survived 1 4047.42

after Filter Survived for 0 is 2399
after Filter Survived for 1 is 4014

Please someone could help me?

Comment: I tried df = df.dropna(axis=0) but no Sucess the command df.groupby('Survived').sum() returns the same values 2481.00 ages for Survived 0 and 4047.42 for Survived 1 that is mistake in excel is 2399 for Survived 0 and 4014 for Survived 1 I dont Know where the error is the database is in this site: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/hesh97/titanicdataset-traincsv

Answer (score 0):

As there is no data with us.. So can't really test it...

But it seems like you are dropping records before groupby where it's null...

I think you need to back assign the df. So try this;

```
df = df.dropna(axis=0)
```

Comment: You can also use `inplace=True`

Comment: No sucess I think is not a non-value problem